# Defining exponential function using functional equations

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, exponential-function, definition

Find continuous functions f: $\mathbb R$->$\mathbb R$ which satisfy the following properties: $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y) \forall x,y \in \mathbb R$, and $f(1)=a$.

I've been struggling with the proof of the theorem.

**My attempt:**

Let $f(a)=1$.
For $y=0$, we have $f(x+0)=f(x)f(0) \implies  f(0)=1 \text{ or } f(0)=0$ . However, if $f(0)=0$, then $f(1)=f(1)(0)=0$ which is a contradiction since we have $f(1)=a$. Therefore, we conclude $f(0)=1$. Now using induction we can easily deduce that for $n\in \mathbb N,$ we get $f(n)=f(1)^n$, also since $1=f(0)=f(1+(-1))=f(1)f(-1)$, we can find the value of $f(-1)$ and uniquely define it on $\mathbb Z$, and using similar methods on $\mathbb Q$. But the problem is defining it on $\mathbb R$. I get that this is the hard part where we need the continuity to 'fill' the gaps. So how do you proceed from this?

Answer (score 1):

Well you have already showed essentially that
$$f|_{\mathbb{Q}}\implies\,~\,~f(q)=a^q\,.$$
The denseness of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and the continuity of $f$ then guarantees a unique such $f$; indeed, for any $r$, we can find a sequence of rational numbers $\{q_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ converging to $r$ such that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f({q_n})= f(\lim_{n\to\infty}{q_n})\,,$$
where the continuity requirement allows the limit and the function to commute (that is, to take the limit “inside” the function). However, the left hand side just becomes
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a^{q_n}=a^r\,$$ implying that the only such function is $f(r)=a^r$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've tried the same but I thought this  reasoning was circular. I was wondering how do we know that the lim f(qn) exists? And if we chose another sequence of rationals (pn) that converge to r, how do we know that lim f(pn)= lim f(qn)? It seems to me that we assumed continuity, but we're trying to prove that such function exists?

Comment: Yes, continuity here implies that $$\lim\circ f=f\circ\lim$$ and that’s what guarantees the uniqueness of $f$.

Comment: Sure, we agree that the continuity guarantees the uniqueness. However, we still don't know that the lim a^q exists. (Because of denseness we know that sequence of rational exists, but that doesn't give us that sequence of f(qn) converges. Right?)

Comment: The limit is with respect to the metric induced by the standard absolute value on $\mathbb{R}$—that is $d(x,y)=|x-y|$, and it is with respect to this that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. (Or do you have in mind a different topology on $\mathbb{R}$ for which $f$ should be deemed continuous$?

Comment: Note that in our standard complete metric space $(\mathbb{R},|\cdot|)$, for a fixed $a>0$, the sequence $\{a^{r_n}\}_{n\ge 1}$ converges to $a^r$ when $\{r_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ converges to $r$, and that’s what I have used in the last step of the proof above.

Comment: Yes, we are using the standard limit. Regards to the second statement, isn't that fact the crux of this proof, thing we have to prove? I noted up there in my statement, this theorem is used as the definiton of exp. f., so in a way we don't know anything about the exp.f. yet.

Comment: No, we already know “continuous” exponential functions. Indeed, we already know that for any $a>0$ any map $$f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}_{>0}\,,~\,~\,~ r\mapsto a^r$$ is continuous, using the standard definition of continuity (say the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity) and that it satisfies $$f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)\,.$$ What we are “now” answering—the crux of the proof, as you say—is whether there is “another” continuous function different from $f$ such that $g(1)=a$ and also satisfies $g(x+y)=g(x)g(y)$, for which the answer is no.